# What are some of the most profitable loyalty store items?

Tags: eve-online

In EVE, one can accumulate large amounts of loyalty points by running missions for various NPC corporations.  These loyalty points combined with cash and sometimes other items can produce expensive faction or corporation-specific items.

Sometimes I've considered "cashing out" the loyalty points in a store to buy it's most profitable items.  That way I could turn all of my loyalty points into sweet liquid cash.

The problem is that there are so many different items that can be purchased at loyalty stores, I don't know which goods are the most profitable to convert. (I've considered faction ammo for instance)

Now I know that market conditions fluctuate constantly, but I bet some items are obvious winners and others are obvious losers.

Can anyone recommend some profitable loyalty store items to sell on the market?

Comment: What's with the close vote?  In my mind this is a valid question about strategy.  One could even offer a mathematical proof in a particular answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, Eve is supply and demand based. What was a good conversion ratio now is not necessarily a good one later.

A good constant however is consumable parts, such as ammo. Caldari Navy Ammo for example currently has a good sell value.

Hardwires are generally quick and easy sells however. It is best to research this yourself by looking into contracts for the factions you do have points towards.

If your looking at which faction has the best cashout ratio however, that is a different question.

Comment: Sometimes, and depending of the space region you're in, +2/3 implants can potentially generate some profit.

Answer (score 2):

The most reliably profitable LP item at the stores for most major corporations are large faction gun ammo, which typically sell at prices that equate to about 1000 isk/LP.

Some of the smaller, research-oriented corporations have more profitable items in their LP stores; for example, Thukker Mix sells Snake implants, which used to provide about 3,000 isk/LP. Missioning for those corporations is also useful because they tend to be the ones with high-level research agents, which are basically Free Money.